# DIY hinge made out of nylon webbing

Tags: hinges

I am helping cleaning up a not for profit shed and one of the cabinets has this interesting fold down door with hinges made out of a nylon strap screwed to both the lower inside side of door and base of the cabinet frame.

They look a lot like "strap hinges" but my searches for the actual name of that approach to DIY hinges have yield no results.

Would anyone know what is the actual name for this sort of hinges?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. Unexcitingly, and rather predictably, I think they're referred to as cloth hinges or fabric hinges (and there appears to be a single reference to textile hinges on YT). More generically they're a specific type of soft hinge, which includes those made of leather as well. Unfortunately I'm sure the term 'soft hinge' will lead to terrible search results, because of modern soft-close hinges. Why the need for a name?

Comment: Hi, perfectionism. I am simply trying ro match styles and components as I was asked if can do something "similar" to what os already in place what but on another cabinet. Where people usually say similar I tend to hear "same" :-)

Comment: Makes perfect sense. But if the existing hinges look as I'm imagining I would imagine they were literally from nylon strapping, rather than being a commercial item. Is there evidence of heat sealing along one or both ends or are they hemmed and sewn?

Comment: I did have another look and yes, you are right, pure webbing with screws and washers on both ends (my recollection was incorrect).

Comment: This sounds like it was something done DIY by a previous maintainer when the "real" hinges failed. Cutting the webbing out of an old lawn chair and using a couple of screws & washers was probably the cheapest option available. Sounds like it's right on track for what you need today.